# Printing n first lines of files in folder separed by filename

Tags: powershell

I want to print the two first lines of each file in a folder, with the filename as a headar This is what I have:

```
Get-ChildItem *.4th | % {$filename = $_.Name 
( $_| Get-Content -First 2) |
% { "{0}`r`n{1}`r`n" -f $filename, $_ }}
```

it works but it treats the two lines as  different items

```
zigzag.4th
\ Taken from xxxxx 

zigzag.4th
\ 4tH version 2010, xxx
```

how I could get the two lines together?

```
zigzag.4th
\ Taken from xxxxx 
\ 4tH version 2010, xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it, added a -join to Get-Content

```
Get-ChildItem *.4th | % {$filename = $_.Name 
($_  | Get-Content -Head 2) -join ("`r`n")| % { 
"`r`n{0}`r`n{1}" -f $filename, $_ }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but you could use just `Select-String` for this with a [`Context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3#-context) value of `1` or `2` depending on the need:

```bash
Select-String -Path *.4th -Pattern ^ -List -Context 2 |
    Select-Object Filename, Line, @{ N='Context'; E={ $_.Context.PostContext -join "`r`n" }} |
    Format-List
```